# Java: reading and writing int values to a file using Scanner and PrintWriter

Tags: java, int, printwriter

I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies but the code is supposed to write the `ci` variable to a txt file everytime the `saveCI` method is called, overwriting any previous int there might or might not have been. When the `loadCI` method is called, whatever int value in written in the txt file needs to be saved to the `ci` variable and if the txt file is completely empty, `ci` is supposed equal **0**. For some reason whenever either method is called nothing happens, the txt file always remains empty.

Here's the code:

```
private int ci;
private File ciFile = new File("ci.txt");

private void saveCI(){
    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ciFile);           
        pw.write(ci);
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("CI saved");
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("CI save" + e);
    }
}

public void loadCI(){
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(ciFile);
        if(sc.hasNextInt() == false){
            ci = 0;
        }else{
            ci = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("CI loaded");
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("load ci " + e);
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that there is more code in the class from which this sample is taken and there is another class with also alot of code in. The save and load methods are called from other methods/classes and I omitted the rest of the code because there is too much to include here. I'm trying to practice the OO methodology.

Comment: `        if(sc.hasNextInt() == false){
            ci = 0;
        }else{
            ci = sc.nextInt();
        }
`
is more simply written as `ci = sc.hasNextInt() ? sc.nextInt() : 0;`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `write(int c)` method of `PrintWriter` interprets its argument as a character, so the zero gets written to the file as the invisible NUL character (numeric value 0) rather than the desired '0' character (numeric value 48).

Calling `pw.print(ci)` instead of `pw.write(ci)` in `saveCI()` should do the trick.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: Thanks dude, that seems to have fixed it. Much appreciate. :)